# How can I show the error from NestJS to my front-end component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nestjs

I have a NestJS application which is working properly. I am making a request and throwing a `BadRequestException` if something fails:

```
// my-service.ts

try {
    return await signUp(...);
} catch (err) {
    throw new BadRequestException({
      description: err.message,
    });

    // have also tried...
    throw new BadRequestException(err.message);
}
```

In the network tab, I can see I'm getting a good error:

> {"description":"An account with the given email already exists."}

I am using VueJS for my front-end, and while I am getting a 400 error back, I'm only able to return a generic error message.

Here is what my request looks like:

```
// my-service.js


const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': null,
        'X-Requested-With': null,
    },
});

...

try {
    const response = await client.post(`/v1/auth/signup`, user, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });

    console.log('resp: ', response);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err: ', err); // Request failed with status code 400
    return Promise.reject(err);
}
```

How can I return the error I am seeing in NestJS, all the way back to Vue so I can render it to the screen?

Comment: what exectly is `client` here?

Comment: Hi @h0p3zZ, I updated my question to provide more info.

Comment: try logging JSON.stringify(err) there you might find the prop you are looking for other than that I can't really help you

Answer (score 1):

Here on this documentation you can se how to do error handling on axios:

https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

So probably you can do something like this to access the message from NestJS:

```
try {
    const response = await client.post(`/v1/auth/signup`, user, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });

    console.log('resp: ', response);
} catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @DSabalsa! the link was helpful as I was not checking the err.response object properly.